# Problem after changing file extension from .cpp to .cu in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I have a CUDA project that originates from a C++ project. I will need to add CUDA code to different compilation units over time. Let's say I have two files, **kernel.cuh** and **kernel.cu** that contain my kernels' headers and bodies. Then, I change the extension of a module from .cpp to .cu, include **kernel.cuh**, and call my kernels using the < syntax (`myKernel<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>`). When I do this, I get an error in the module that says `syntax error: <` . The problem is that this file is still compiled by the  C++ compiler instead of nvcc, and I don't know how to change that in Visual Studio manually. I thought the compiler was chosen according to the extension of the files. The problem wouldn't go away until I create a new project from scratch. Does anyone know how to fix this so that I will not need to create a new project?

Comment: Calling a kernel can only be done from a .cu file. And it's not enough to change the file extension, the nVidia compiler must be used. You can create a new cuda example project from the VS wizard to get all the required settings.

Answer (score 1):

For the question to get off the unanswered list, I will give a simple solution that solves the problem but does not answer my question about VS. I didn't have to make a new project from scratch. I only had to remove the file from the project and then add it again (Idk why I hadn't tried this before).